# angular 2: extend Response class

Tags: angular

I'm new to `Angular 2` and I'm tying to extend the Response class.
Basicly what im trying to do is, for each response (before returning to the object who invoked the request) I want to check the response status and do something with it. For exmaple if the response status was `401` then navigate to the login screen.

this is what i have so far:

```
export class MyResponse extends Response {
  constructor(responseOptions: ResponseOptions) {
    super(responseOptions);
  }
```

and Im my Boot:

```
provide(Response, {useClass: MyResponse}),
```

When running this im getting :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getOptional' of undefined_runAppInitializers @ application_ref.js:224PlatformRef_._initApp @ application_ref.js:205PlatformRef_.application @ application_ref.js:153bootstrap @ browser.js:101(anonymous function) @ app.js:59DecorateConstructor @ Reflect.js:536decorate @ Reflect.js:98__decorate @ app.bundle.js:3181(anonymous function) @ app.ts:13(anonymous function) @ app.ts:56__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap e77d89d…:19(anonymous function) @ bootstrap e77d89d…:39__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap e77d89d…:19(anonymous function) @ bootstrap e77d89d…:39(anonymous function) @ bootstrap e77d89d…:39(anonymous function) @ travesseyJwtHttp.ts:46__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap e77d89d…:19(anonymous function) @ app.ts:7__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap e77d89d…:19(anonymous function) @ bootstrap e77d89d…:39__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap e77d89d…:19(anonymous function) @ bootstrap e77d89d…:39(anonymous function) @ bootstrap e77d89d…:39
>    `

Is there a better way to do what I,m trying to?

Comment: How does you `bootstrap(...)` call look like. Are `HTTP_PROVIDERS` listed before the `provide(Response, ...)`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes

Comment: Any hint which class causes the `Cannot read property getOptional of undefined? Are you sure this is caused by the `MyResponse` class?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Almost 100% because when removing the `provide(..)` it works well

Answer (score 2):

In fact, after having a look at the implementation of the `XHRConnection` class (see https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/http/backends/xhr_backend.ts#L59), the `Response` can't be changed through dependency injection since it's directly instantiated when the response is received.

If you want to intercept responses, I think that the approach would be to extend the `Http` object itself and leverage the `catch` operator:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    console.log('request...');
    return super.request(url, options).catch(res => {
      // do something
    });        
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    console.log('get...');
    return super.get(url, options).catch(res => {
      // do something
    });
  }
}
```

Thie `CustomHttp` class can be registered as described below:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    new Provider(Http, {
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) => new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions),
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
  })
]);
```

If 401 errors occur as this level, you can "catch" them within the callback you provided for `catch` operators.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like only the `@Injectable()` annotation is missing

```
@Injectable()
export class MyResponse extends Response {
  constructor(responseOptions: ResponseOptions) {
    super(responseOptions);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know why MyResponse is not picked up automatically when Http is used? Instead default Response is still used. http://plnkr.co/edit/VJVkuNBn5NZjumKJV93Q?p=preview

Comment: It looks like you also need a custom implementation of `XHRConnection`. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f2c7946cca76ab0013970b9cb013db928072fecb/modules/angular2/src/http/backends/xhr_backend.ts#L59 `new Response(responseOptions);` :-/ It would need to use some factory for `Response`. Angular DI maintains single instances and `Response` can't be reused between requests.